# Dart aot compilation doesn't work with docker

Tags: docker, dart

I'm trying to use a dart server with aot, and works fine on local, but when I try to dockerize the server, it is not accessible.

I created a repo with some examples, and it seems a network problem with aot.

The repo:
https://github.com/DavidBernal/dart-aot-docker

You can try to build + run the dockerfile or use docker-compose, the result is the same.